# Android WebCam streaming in WebView

Tags: android, webview, video-streaming, webcam, android-videoview

I need to display a video stream (pointing to a webcam) with url:
videostream.cgi?user=user&pwd=pw
Immediately I thought it was enough to simply load the url in a WebView:

```
 webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);

String url="http://192.168.1.3/videostream.cgi?user=user&pwd=pw";
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);     
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);     
webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

The address I post is right. In fact, if I insert for example firefox address, is transmitted video stream of the webcam. With firebug I see that there is a with the "src". Obviously I have the permissions of the internet in the manifest fact appear well sites.

But I soon realized that I am not working. But I can not finding a solution .. I still will fail to see the web cam.
Can anyone give me a tip?
Doing something wrong or what alternatives can I use?

thanks

Comment: Open the URL in the browser and see if it works. If it does, check the page-source to make sure it's not wrapping the actual stream in a viewer or element. If it does, use that.

Comment: `.setPluginState()` is deprecated